# Why are Mockito argument matchers unable to match with my builder-pattern object?

Tags: java, junit, mockito, builder, argumentcaptor

I have a class similar to the following:

```
package com.example.objects;

import java.util.Objects;

public class MyExampleClass extends SomeBaseClass {

    private String param1;
    private String param2;

    private MyExampleClass(String param1, String param2) {
        this.param1 = param1;
        this.param2 = param2;
    }

    MyExampleClass() {
    }

    public String getParam1() {
        return param1;
    }

    public String getParam2() {
        return param2;
    }

    public static class Builder {
        private String param1;
        private String param2;

        public Builder setParam1(String param1) {
            this.param1 = param1;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setParam2(String param2) {
            this.param2 = param2;
            return this;
        }
        
        public MyExampleClass build() {
            Objects.requireNonNull(param1,"blahblah");
            Objects.requireNonNull(param2,"blahblah");
            return new MyExampleClass(param1, param2);
        }
    }
}
```

and in a Groovy unit test I want to do something like the following:

```
def captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(MyExampleClass)
Mockito.verify(mockObject).someMethod(captor.capture())
```

I expect I would be able to make assertions off of my captor as per usual, however instead I get something along the lines of:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
mockObject.someMethod(
 <Capturing argument>
);
-> at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)

However, there was exactly 1 interaction with this mock:
mockObject.someMethod(
    com.example.objects.MyExampleClass@47a7a101
);
```

What am I doing wrong that prevents ArgumentMatchers and ArgumentCaptors from recognizing my object?

Comment: What is `someMethod` and what has the builder got to do with anything of this?

Comment: @knittl some method is a stand-in for any method that has a parameter of type MyExampleClass. I am always unable to use captors or matchers on MyExampleClass no matter where it's used. I don't know what the builder has to do with any of this, however since this is the only class in my codebase that has this issue, and it is the only class implementing this pattern, it seems relevant.

Comment: Shouldn't `forCaptor(MyExampleClass)` be `forCaptor(MyExampleClass.class)`? Does the error still occur if you remove the builder from the class?

Comment: As I mentioned the test class is in Groovy, so yes that would also work, but Groovy does not need `.class`